# Wired ethernet not getting detected in 10.04

Tags: networking

Ubuntu version : 10.04
Desktop Model  : HP 8200 Elite SFF

> **Prob           : ethernet not being detected.**

Please help. I am new to Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[According to HP](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13879_na/13879_na.HTML#Technical%20Specifications%20-%20Communications), the 8200 Elite SFF has an Intel network controller. Normally this shouldn't be a problem in Ubuntu, but it might be in 10.04. I'm going to need a little more information so I can see what's happening.

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or Applications > Accessories > Terminal) and execute the following command:

```
lspci -nn
```

Or don't, because I totally just realized you probably don't have Internet access on that machine. The relevant line from `lspci` is the one containing "Ethernet controller".

Do the same for this command, if there is any output.

```
dmesg | grep e100
```